# My cat (3 yrs) fell into my bathtub of diluted shampoo. After licking himself clean he has been sneezing non-stop for 3 days. Would this be why?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, safety

He has been acting normal besides the fact that he sneezes constantly. Not purring as much, considering. Just wondering if he has a little cat cold or if the diluted shampoo water he fell into had something to do with his situation. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Constant sneezing should be checked out by your vet, typically this would be a sign of an upper respiratory infection, or potentially obstruction by foreign objects. In case of fluid buildup in the lungs after a near-drowning event, you'd typically expect coughing instead of sneezing, but I would highly suggest to cover your bases here and consult with your vet.

Comment: Even if it not an infection or a foreign object there, it might still be some allergic reaction. So a trip to the vet is still the proper way to handle the issue.

Comment: The shampoo water got inside his system. He probably also has a bad cold.

Answer (score 1):

Take your cat to the vet.
Even if the shampoo is diluted, the cat could still become sick from ingesting the chemicals.